# Use grep to replace every nth and (n+1)th occurrence with different values in R

Tags: r, regex

For quarterly data

```
> df  
  TIME     GEO  Value
2000Q1 Austria 3864.6   
2000Q2 Austria 3841.3   
2000Q3 Austria 3843.0   
2000Q4 Austria 3847.2   
2001Q1 Austria 3853.5   
2001Q2 Austria 3875.2   
2001Q3 Austria 3886.7  
2001Q4 Austria 3921.9   
2002Q1 Austria 3865.2   
2002Q2 Austria 3872.4  
2002Q3 Austria 3876.0  
2002Q4 Austria 3887.9   
2003Q1 Austria 3938.3   
2003Q2 Austria 3954.5  
2003Q3 Austria 3972.8  
2003Q4 Austria 3971.9
```

I'm naively converting quarterly data to monthly with
`df.mon <- rep(df$Value, each=3)`.  I do the same for `df$TIME`

```
 df.mon$TIME <- rep(df$TIME, each=3)
```

I want to convert these time identifiers to monthly ones so that I can easily use `df.mon` as a weight on monthly data.

So, I have

```
  >head(df.mon, n=10)
     GEO  month
  3864.6 2000Q1
  3864.6 2000Q1
  3864.6 2000Q1
  3841.3 2000Q2
  3841.3 2000Q2
  3841.3 2000Q2
  3843.0 2000Q3
  3843.0 2000Q3
  3843.0 2000Q3
  3847.2 2000Q4
```

I want replace the 1st, 4th, 7th, etc. occurrence of `Q1` with `M01`, and the 2nd, 5th, 8th, etc. occurence of `Q1` with `M02` and so on, to produce:

```
     GEO  month
  3864.6 2000M01
  3864.6 2000M02
  3864.6 2000M03
  3841.3 2000M04
  3841.3 2000M05
  3841.3 2000M06
  3843.0 2000M07
```

The closest explanation to this is [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/textwrangler/vhxo7HmYuS0), and seems like using `grep` with back references `\1` is the way to go (a useful list is [here](http://mauricio-diazgranados.com/index.php/grep-formulas)).

I've tried,

```
gsub("(?:Q1)", "\\1M01\\2M02\\3M03", df.mon$month)
```

which only gives me

```
     2000M01M02M03
     2000M01M02M03
     2000M01M02M03
```

I've tried other specifications like `gsub("(?:Q1)(?:Q1)(?:Q1)", "\\1M01\\2M02\\3M03", df.mon$month)`, for which no replacements are made.

I don't really understand what's going on with the `(?: )` command (and it seems unnecessary), and I don't know Perl so I'm at a loss for how to make this seemingly easy replacement work.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
year <- grep("[0-9]{4}", df.mon$month, value=T)
month <- paste("M", 1:12, sep="")
yearmonth <- paste(year, month, sep="")
df.mon$month <- yearmonth
```

No complicated reg expressions needed.

Comment: Thanks.   This almost works.  The `grep` doesn't remove the "Q1" at the end of the string.  But using `year <- substr(df.mon$month, 1, 4)` does the trick.   However, the `paste` command doesn't quite work because I need all month values to have two digits, i.e., `M01`, `M02`, ..., `M12`.

Comment: This worked for my purposes:        `year <- substr(df.mon$month, 1, 4)    
           month <- paste("M", sprintf("%02d", 1:12), sep="")
           yearmonth <- paste(year, month, sep="")
           df.mon$month <- yearmonth`.   This works because all my country-level data starts and end in the same quarter.  In general, I'm still interested in knowing how to implement a find-and-replace solution.

Comment: Find and Replace is the wrong strategy because programmatically that is not what you are doing. You are not finding a specific value and replacing it with another specific value. You are replacing a set of values with a new set of values with a different pattern.